# importing qmc as submodule in scipy

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

When I write from `scipy.stats import qmc` I face Import Error in Jupyter notebook:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'qmc' from 'scipy.stats' (C:\winapps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py)
```

I want to do Halton sampling, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

The `qmc` module was added in version 1.7.0 of scipy (around July 2021).  You probably need to update the package.  Since you are using Anaconda, you can use:

```
conda install scipy=1.7
```

Although this might break you base environment.  Instead, you would better off creating a new environment using conda:

```
conda create -n myenv scipy=1.7 pandas ipykernel
```